# Cardinality of inclusion-relation on the power set of a finte set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $X$ be a finite set with relation $R_\subseteq \subseteq 2^X \times 2^X$ defined via $((Y,Z) \in R_\subseteq) := (Y \subseteq Z)$ for $Y,Z \in 2^X$.

What is $|R_\subseteq|$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try $|R_\subseteq| = 3^{|X|}$. Can you take it from here?